# Can I call two function on useEffect hook ? It complains controlled input to be uncontrolled?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have bellow two function I want to call on useEffect Hook but it complains.

Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

How do I solve this issue ? Thank you..

```
  const product_properties_list = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/admin/product_properties/product_properties_list');
    setState({product_properties_list: res.data});
  }

  const single_property_value = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/admin/property_values/property_values_edit/${id}`)
    setState({
      property_values_name: res.data.property_values_name,
      validator: [],
      message:''
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    product_properties_list();
    single_property_value();
    
  }, [])
```

**jsx code**

```
return (
          <>
          <div className="container text-center mt-5">
            <form className="fff" onSubmit={property_values_edit}>
              <div className="border border-success col-4 offset-4 p-1">
                 
                <div className="mb-3 form-floating text-left">
                  <select name="product_properties_id"  onChange={handleInput} className="form-control" required>
                    <option value="0">SELECT</option>
                    {state.product_properties_list.map(product_properties_single => (
                      <option key={product_properties_single.id} value={product_properties_single.id}>{product_properties_single.product_properties_name}</option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
                  
                </div> 
                
                
                <div className="mb-3 form-floating text-left">
                  <input name="property_values_name" value={state.property_values_name} onChange={handleInput} type="text" className="form-control" id="property_values_name" required />
                  <label htmlFor="property_values_name">Property Values Name:</label>
                </div>
                
                <div className="form-floating">
                  <button className="btn btn-md btn-primary col-12" type="submit">Property Values Update</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div> 
          </>
        );
```

Comment: the problem is related to the `input` tag , please attach the code where input is used.

Comment: @Shan Hey, I have updated my question with input tag. Please have a look. Thank you..

Comment: Are you getting the `res` ? and Please add setState initialization

Comment: @Shan I am getting `res`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input field `value` was defined initially and then later it was set to `undefined`.
You are setting the `property_values_name` property in the **state** object
to `undefined` by doing `setState({product_properties_list: res.data});`, i.e replacing the whole **state** with `{product_properties_list: res.data}`.

```
const product_properties_list = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/admin/product_properties/product_properties_list');
  setState(currState => ({...currState, product_properties_list: res.data}));
}
```

Do `setState` from current state , so that you wont set the `property_values_name` to `undefined`

Comment: Still getting `state.product_properties_list` is undefined !

Comment: Okay, I got it now. It's working fine on save but on reload I have found the same error on the console as the question

Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled.

Comment: @KamrulHasan can you update the code with `useState` initialization and where else you are calling `setState`. `Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled.` this warning is different from your question

Comment: here is my full code on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/YGbpwXg8

Please have a look

Comment: `state.single_property_value` is an array but you are trying to get property_values_name from it  `value={state.single_property_value.property_values_name}`

Comment: I have changed `state.single_property_value` to object {} but error remains same on reload.

Comment: Would you please recheck line 55&65 on the pastebin: https://pastebin.com/YGbpwXg8. I am getting `res.data` for the both cases but found empty `state.product_properties_list && state.single_property_value` on console.log()

Comment: You cannot read the `state` in console.log immeadiately after setting it

Comment: `value={state.single_property_value.property_values_name || ""}` Provide a fallback `""` in value attribute for `input`.This will assign empty string to value if `state.single_property_value.property_values_name` is undefined/null (falsy values)